# Any way to set a default tag for all objects uploaded into an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

s3 lifecycle rules can be created based on the existence of a tag, or the value of a tag.  However, they cannot be created based on the absence of a tag.

Is there any way to set a default tag for all objects uploaded to a bucket?

That way I can set up a default lifecycle rule based on that tag, and then if I want something different, simply use a different tag to override the rule.

I know we can specify a tag when uploading an object from the code that is doing the uploading.  However, we have a number of different mechanisms that result in an uploaded object, so I am hoping to have a central solution.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not possible to specify a "default tag". Worst case, you could create an Amazon S3 Event that triggers an AWS Lambda function that applies a tag to newly-created objects.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That is what we are leaning towards, but I wanted to put a feeler out just in case there is something we are missing.  Thanks for the comment.